# Unique locale yml path for /new and /edit when using partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, locale, yaml, rails-i18n

I'm using the partial _form for both `new` and `edit` action/view.

This is what I have in the form: `t(".change_image")`

The missing locale path generated by Rails is the following

```
translation missing: en.users.form.change_image
```

But I would like to have different text in `en.yml` if it's the `new` or `edit` view, i.e. "Add image" and "Change image".

How would I get unique locale paths reflecting the action and not the partial? E.g.

```
en:
  users:
    new:
      change_image:
```

Comment: [translate](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper/translate) scopes the key by the current partial if the key starts with a period, so you will have to use full path.

Comment: How do you mean "full path"? How would I get a unique path for /new  and /edit respectively?

Comment: Using string substitution? `t("users.#{params[:action]}.change_image")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[translate](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper/translate) scopes the key by the current partial if the key starts with a period, so you will have to use full path in `t()`. like,

```
t("users.#{params[:action]}.change_image")
```